# Block all caps sentences

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use a regex expression to block all caps sentences (sentences with only capital letters) but I can't succeed at finding the pattern. I was thinking about ^[a-z] but this doesn't work at all.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Which language/tool you are using..If it's winforms you can use `KeyPressed` event to block capital text..You don't need regex for this unless there's no other way

Comment: It would help if you added what flavour of regex/what language or libraries you're using to the question. Many regex flavours support different functions so one answer might not work for all languages. But this is a good question that I can't find answered anywhere else. Just to clarify: you are looking of a way to match where the letter characters in a sentence are entirely upper case?

Comment: Just get rid of the first `^` and use `[a-z]`. If that matches, the sentence is not all caps.

Comment: Do you care only about avoiding uppercase [A-Z] and allowing lowercase [a-z]?  Do you want to allow numbers, punctuation, etc, or do you want to only allow some limited range of characters?

Answer (score 1):

You can perhaps use something like this to make sure there's at least one lowercase character (note that's this is some kind of reverse logic):

```
^.*[a-z].*$
```

(Unless the function you're using uses regex against the whole pattern by default, you can drop the beginning and end of line anchors)

If you want the regex to be more strict (though I don't think that's very practical here), you can perhaps use something of the sort...

```
^[A-Z.,:;/() -]*[A-Z]+[A-Z.,:;/() -]*$
```

To allow only uppercase letters, and some potential punctuations (you can add or remove them from the character classes as you need) and spaces.

Comment: `[a-z]` does the same as the first, no?

Comment: @beroe Yes, in most context, that can work, but there are functions that test a regex pattern against a whole string (or anchor the pattern by default), for example in python, `re.match(r'[a-z]', 'Abc')` will fail to match, but `re.search(r'[a-z]', 'Abc')` will find a match, hence why I used the `.*` so that it will work regardless of the function. Of course, I'm all for going for the simpler(est) solution :)

Comment: I gotcha. Hard/impossible to tell what is required given the level of detail in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply look for `[a-z]`... If that matches, your sentence passes. If not, it is all caps (or punctuation).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what flavour of regex you're using but if you have one that supports lookaheads then you can use the following expression:

```
(?-i)^(?!(?=.*?[A-Z])(?:[A-Z]|(?i)[^a-z])*$)
```

It won't capture anything but will return false if the letters used are all in caps, and return true if any of the letters used are lower case.

Comment: I'm sure this could be made more concise, it feels like it could be shorter but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can't `^[A-Z]+$` simply suit your needs? If it matches, it means that the input string contains only capital letters.

Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?36kf1).

Comment: I think the idea was that it would match any normally structured sentence (punctuation etc) where every letter character is in uppercase. I assume maybe it's to try and combat spam messages?

Comment: @JonM Instead of keeping strings that match yours, you can simply remove strings that match mine, result will be quite identical ;)

Comment: What about cases where there is punctuation? You could have a sentence that would be considered 'ALL CAPS' but also includes punctuation and numbers etc.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex

```
(^|\.)[[:space:]A-Z]+\.
```

will find any *line* containing only uppercase letters and whitespace between either start of line, or the preceding full stop.

Comment: Without more context, it's hard to say if it's completely suitable for your needs, but because your question is vague (it doesn't even tell us which language you are using) perhaps you can take it from there, or post a more complete question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to detect sentences that have words that have upper case nested inside the word, ex: hEllo, gOODbye, worD; that is any word that has an uppercase after a lower case, or any word with two or more uppercase beside each other.

- uppercase after lowercase

  [a-z][A-Z]
- two or more paired uppercase

  [A-Z][A-Z]

Combined them with alternation,

```
/*([a-z][A-Z]|[A-Z][A-Z])/
```